# You must add a reference to assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, openxml

I'm currently writing up an upload system that takes XML from the document and will display it on a web page.

The issue I'm facing, is that whenever I'm adding the XML extraction part of the website, the compiler will return the error as mentioned in the title. I have already added WindowsBase, both from manually and from the drop down menu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check properties of the referenced assembly (select reference and click F4) - try to use "Copy Local: true"

Comment: Thanks very much. Most of the references are still set to false, what difference does it make adding this to true, does it override the framework version or something?

Comment: No, there is no need to set this setting for all references. 
The issue is that IIS couldn't find WindowsBase.dll because it's not registered in the GAC. And it wasn't located in your website's /bin folder.
Setting 'Copy Local' to true forces compiler to copy this library to your /bin folder.